# How to append an array with a value at particular index for a key in NSMutableDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I would like to know how to append an array with a value at particular index for a key in NSMutableDictionary in Swift?

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
let xyz: NSMutableDictionary = ["1":[1,2,3,4,"1","n"],"2":[1,2,3,4,"+","o","6","2"]]
```

I want to add to key "1" a value of 1 at index 6 i.e. It should look like:

```
let xyz: NSMutableDictionary = ["1":[1,2,3,4,"1","n",1],"2":[1,2,3,4,"+","o","6","2"]]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose the method to (for a given key, in your example `"1"`)

- extract a mutable copy the value array,
- mutate this copy,
- overwrite the original array (value) for the given key,

you need to tell (in this case, attempt to cast) Swift that that the value array is *an array* of instances of type `AnyObject` (i.e., `[AnyObject]`), otherwise, as per default, the key will be extracted as a single `AnyObject`. Only for the former will Swift realize we can append elements (to an array), whereas for the latter, Swift wont allow us to append elements to a single `AnyObject` value (even if it wraps an array).

E.g.

```
let xyz: NSMutableDictionary = ["1":[1,2,3,4,"1","n"],"2":[1,2,3,4,"+","o","6","2"]]

let appendValue = "1"
let forKey = "1"
if var arr = xyz[forKey] as? [AnyObject] {
    arr.append(appendValue)
    xyz[forKey] = arr
}
```

resulting in

```
print(xyz)

{
    1 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        1,
        n,
        1
    );
    2 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        "+",
        o,
        6,
        2
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary contains key / value pairs. The values or arrays. You want to change one of the values. To do that, if the value itself (the array) is modifiable then you read the value for the key "1", and modify it. If the value is not modifiable, then you read the old value for the key "1", create a new array containing what you want it to contain, and store that new value again under the key "1".

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var res = xyz["1"] //the result is the array
res.append(1) // assuming you can change the array
```

If you can't change the array,
you will need something like

```
var res = xyz["1"]
var newArr = res
newArr.append(1)
xyz["1"] = newArr
```

Comment: Is it not slower to append it like that?

Comment: And the array can not be appended because it has a different class than usual Swift Array, which is due to NSMutableDict.

Comment: So just use the four lines I wrote in case you can't change the array. There you creating a new array, so you can append to it.

Comment: Apparently it's of type AnyObject which makes it immutable.